# How do i pivot or transpose specific columns in a table in R?

Tags: r, pivot-table, transpose

I have an income dataset that looks like this.

| CITY | 2014 | 2015 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 21 | 22 |
| BB | 21 | 24 |

I am trying to find a way to make the dataset look like this.

| CITY | Income | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 21 | 2014 |
| AA | 21 | 2014 |
| BB | 22 | 2015 |
| BB | 24 | 2015 |

I tried to pivot this using the tidyr package but I've not been successful so far. Is there any other package or code that would allow for this transformation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `pivot_longer`. Keep in mind that R doesn't like numbers as column names.

```
df <- tibble(city=c("AA","BB"), `2014`=c(21,21), `2015`=c(22, 24))
df %>% pivot_longer(c(`2014`, `2015`), names_to="Year", values_to="Income")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  city  Year  Income
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 AA    2014      21
2 AA    2015      22
3 BB    2014      21
4 BB    2015      24
```

Comment: Thank you PeterK! Too new to cast an upvote but this works for me :)

Comment: @DayaV, please do give a check to select a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Daya!  In the future, please try to post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  These help respondents better understand and diagnose your issues.

You can accomplish what you are after using the `pivot_longer()` function in the `tidyr` package.  Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyr)
city<-c("AA", "BB")
y14<-c(21, 21)
y15<-c(22,24)

DF<-data.frame(city, y14, y15)
colnames(DF)<-c("CITY",2014, 2015)

DF %>% pivot_longer(cols= c(2:3), names_to="Year", values_to="Income")
```

Comment: Thank you Sean for the welcome and the heads up! Will definitely include reproducible examples in my next post. This code also works for me :)